# Воссоздать базу Firebase Realtime Database по коду, возможно ли?

Tags: firebase, firebase-database, realtime

Есть древний проект на гитхабе который не обновляется, хочу сделать форк.

Как узнать структуру базы чтобы воссоздать на своем фаербейсе?

Проект работает с Firebase Realtime Database. проект https://github.com/5cr1p7/FoodsharingRus

Comment: тут походу https://github.com/5cr1p7/FoodsharingRus только клиентская часть расположена, только по АПИ можно попробовать предположить как БД устроена и самому ее реализовать

Comment: пыталась отловить пакеты , но фаербейс не принимает сертификат и не дает расшифровать пакеты переданные

Comment: данные пакета, не расскажут как устроена БД, смысла нет... а вот изучить АПИ клиента и понять что он передает и что ожидает - смысл есть....